# Unable to change Span text using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and JQuery.

> HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li><strong> Status : </strong><span id="monitorStatusSpan">1111</span></li>
    </ul>           
</div>

<button type="button" id="disableButton"
                    class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeSpan();">Change</button>
```

> JavaScript

```
function changeSpan() {
 $('#monitorStatusSpan span').text('disssssssssssssssssss');   
}
```

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/alamzeeshan/5bw8d2ta/7/

But still the span text is not getting changed.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, you're looking for a `span` inside your `#monitorStatusSpan` (`#monitorStatusSpan span`).

```
function changeSpan() {
    $('#monitorStatusSpan span').text('disssssssssssssssssss');   
}
```

It's enough to only look for the ID like this:

```
function changeSpan() {
    $('#monitorStatusSpan').text('Your text here');   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have incorrect selector. Selector you have used finds `#monitorStatusSpan` element and then span element in it. which do not exist.

As IDs are unique, you can simply use id selector to target the required element:

```
function changeSpan() {
 $('#monitorStatusSpan').text('disssssssssssssssssss');   
}
```

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fvqnyyzn/)**

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><strong> Status : </strong><span id="monitorStatusSpan">1111</span></li>
    </ul>           
</div>

<button id="disableMonitorButton" class="btn btn-primary">Change</button>
```

JS

```
$("#disableMonitorButton").click(function() {
    $('#monitorStatusSpan').html('disssssssssssssssssss');  
});
```

PS. DONT USE inline JS!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function changeSpan() {
 $('#monitorStatusSpan').text('disssssssssssssssssss');   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul>
       <li><strong> Status : </strong><span id="monitorStatusSpan">1111</span></li>
    </ul>           
</div>
<button type="button" id="disableButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeSpan();">Change</button>
```

Your current selector selects all `span`'s inside element with id `#monitorStatusSpan` but in this element there are not any `span's`.

For your current selector html should look like this

```
<span id="monitorStatusSpan"><span>TEST</span></span>
```